# WidgetRegistry object has no attribute values

Tags: python, ipywidgets

When I am using Python Widgets with the following code as described in the documentation https://test-widgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.Widget.widget_types.values()
```

Then the following error is thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'WidgetRegistry' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was obsolete and `widget_types` has not anymore the method `values()`. You should use `items()` instead. Here is a possible solution:

```
for element in widgets.Widget.widget_types.items():       
    print element[0][2] + ' ----- ' + str(element[0][5])
```